# Test of sending & receiving message for Azure Service Bus Queue

Tags: python, testing, integration-testing, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I would like to write an integration test checking connection of the Python script with Azure Service Bus queue. The test should:

1. send a message to a queue,
2. confirm that the message landed in the queue.

The test looks like this:

```
import pytest

from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage, ServiceBusSender

CONNECTION_STRING = <some connection string>
QUEUE = <queue name>


def send_message_to_service_bus(sender: ServiceBusSender, msg: str) -> None:
    message = ServiceBusMessage(msg)
    sender.send_message(message)


class TestConnectionWithQueue:
    def test_message_is_sent_to_queue_and_received(self):
        msg = "test message sent to queue"
        expected_message = ServiceBusMessage(msg)
        
        servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STRING, logging_enable=True)
        with servicebus_client:
            sender = servicebus_client.get_queue_sender(queue_name=QUEUE)
            with sender:
                send_message_to_service_bus(sender, expected_message)
        
            receiver = servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver(queue_name=QUEUE)
            with receiver:
                messages_in_queue = receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=10, max_wait_time=20)
        assert any(expected_message == str(actual_message) for actual_message in messages_in_queue)
```

The test occassionally works, more often than not it doesn't. There are no other messages sent to the queue at the same time. As I debugged the code, if the test does not work, the variable `messages_in_queue` is just an empty list.

Why doesn't the code work at all times and what should be done to fix it?

Comment: Please edit your question and include code for `send_message_to_service_bus` method.

Comment: Thanks for catching this! Code updated.

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering how many messages are in the queue?

Comment: When I debug the code and check the variable `messages_in_queue` there is either the one I'm sending by this code snippet or none.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't have another process that receive your messages ? Maybe you are sharing your queue connections strings with other colleagues, build machines...

To troubleshoot you need to keep an eye on the Queue monitoring on Azure Portal. Debug your test and look at incoming messages if it increment by 1. Then continue your debug and check if it decrement by 1.

Also, are you sure that this unit test is useful? It looks like you are testing your infra instead of testing your code